# Using node to proxy external traffic from container through other service mock the response

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy, mocking, docker-compose

I have a node application which i want to write integration tests for. For that to work i need to be able to mock requests for both http requests and websocket.
I use `docker-compose` to define my app dependencies. The relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - proxycontainer
    environment:
      HTTP_PROXY: proxycontainer:8080
      NO_PROXY: localhost,127.0.0.1
  proxycontainer:
    build: ./proxy
```

I have a simple `Dockerfile` for the node app

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine as base

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm install \
    && apk del .gyp

FROM base as build

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
```

The proxy `Dockerfile` looks like

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "proxy" ]
```

Where `npm run proxy` is running `node ./index.js` on this simple file

```
const express = require('express')
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

const app = express()

app.use('/', proxy({ target: 'http://www.example.org', changeOrigin: true, logLevel: 'debug' }))

app.listen(8080)
```

To test just the proxy i have replaced my app with

```
const testProxy = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get("http://example.org/");
  console.log(data.data)
}

testProxy()
```

When running this example i get the error `Error: connect EINVAL 0.0.31.144:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)`

So how do i proxy external requests from one node docker service into a node proxy service, which then can mock the response for http and websocket connections?

If i remove the `HTTP_PROXY` env variable everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using a `http://` prefix before your proxy container's name?

```
HTTP_PROXY: http://proxycontainer:8080
```

You might also create a custom network and assign a local IP address to each container, so you could access them using a static IP.

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - proxycontainer
    environment:
      HTTP_PROXY: http://172.28.1.2:8080/
      NO_PROXY: localhost,127.0.0.1
    networks:
      proxy_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.1
  proxycontainer:
    build: ./proxy
    networks:
      proxy_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.2

networks:
  proxy_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

Comment: Traveling here from the future to thank you for this post. I read like 30 other posts that didn't fix my problem, because I was just missing the http:// before my container name lol.